# Connection with TN5250j works while IBMi access v1r1 (and JT400 library) does not

Tags: java, authentication, ibm-midrange, jt400

Few days ago my correctly working java application stated to throw "General security error" while connecting to AS400. I use JT400 library for connect. After some debugging I also find out I cannot connect with IBMi access v1r1 (5250 emulator from IBM). System i Navigator also does not work. This is print screen from login (errors are same for java application): [image]

But connecting with TN5250J emulator works! I guess problem is with "Not authorized to object /QSYS.LIB/EN_US.LOCALE". I tried connecting with two users. One is my programming user and it works normally when connected through TN5250J. Other one is database access user that I cannot check because it has disabled access through terminal. Using same application on different system (V5R4) works correctly. Looking into job log I found nothing.

Why is /QSYS.LIB/EN_US.LOCALE accessed during signon (and it is not accessed from TN5250J)? What could affect signon process so that it no longer works with IBM emulator/library while it still works with TN5250J? Are there some connection properties in JT400 library that could affect what happens during signon so I could connect like with TN5250J?

Also please someone create tag TN5250J. I think it should be here and I have no reputation to create it!

Comment: I found an old [article](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg092006-story03.html) describing a similar issue and the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in [article](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg092006-story03.html) suggested by JamesA works. Our admin did it and I have my access back. But our admin has no idea how issue was created in the first place. 
Solution from article:

> 1. Execute the Work with Object Links command (WRKLNK) to view the Root (/) directory of the AS/400 IFS.
>      WRKLNK OBJ('/')
> 2. In front of the AS/400 IFS directory object (specified by a single '/'), enter a '9' to work with the Root (/) object's authority.
> 3. If *PUBLIC authority is equal to *EXCLUDE, place a '2' in front of the *PUBLIC entry, press enter and add the following authorities for the *PUBLIC user:
>      Under the New Data Authorities parameter (DTAAUT), enter *RWX so that the user has read, write, and execute in the Root (/) directory.
>      Under the New Object Authorities parameter (OBJAUT), enter the following authorities:
>      *OBJMGT: Object management authority
>      *OBJEXIST: Object existence authority
>      *OBJALTER: Object alter authority
>      *OBJREF: Object reference authority
> 4. Press Enter and save your changes.

TN5250J worked because error does not happen during login (for example through green screen) but instead it happens during initialization - when you start IBMi Access and GUI window will sometimes prompt for login. Since TN5250j does not do this it works. In IBMi Access when in first prompt I specify user with *ALLOBJ authority I can then login through green screen normally with my normal user. JT400 library probably just combines logic for initialization and login!